# SQL Server 2017 and SSRS on Same Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sql-server-2017

I heard that you cannot have SSRS and SQL Server on the same server, I have not been able to find anything that says this or otherwise, is this a true fact?

Comment: One of the changes in SQL Server 2017 is that the SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) installation is not part of the regular SQL Server installation.

Comment: The only thing that's different is that for 2017, Report Services is now a separate, stand-alone install process. You can install SSRS on the same machine as your SQL Server instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not. You can have both of them running on the same server. Here is a screenshot of SQL Server 2017 Database Engine and Power BI Report Server (newest version of SSRS):

[image: SQL Server 2017 and PBIRS]

Answer (score 1):

You can install `SSRS` on the same machine as your SQL Server instance. As per mssqltips Blog [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5237/installing-sql-server-reporting-services-2017/) and MSDN BOL [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/10/02/sql-server-2017-reporting-services-now-generally-available/) One of the changes in SQL Server 2017 is that the SQL Server Reporting Services (`SSRS`) installation is not part of the regular SQL Server installation.